# SKRequest didFailWithError

Tags: iphone, ios4, storekit, nserror

```
-(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error  
{

}
```

With in this method one could arrest the error that happened for ex - ("Failed to Connect to iTunes") etc. Now if one wants to show this error message as an alert it would be really helpful for users. Like one example is when the "Failed to Connect to iTunes" error is shown as an UIAlertView, it can lead the user to the problem that his wi-fi was off all this while. He can rectify this problem and retry. But before one chooses to display these errors as UIAlertView, one must know all the possible error values that are returned because a user won't be pleased to see something like "Error %^@)$()(!)#()+! code 123_123443 blah"i.e.something incomprehensible to him. How to best handle this ? As an after thought, it would be nice to know all the possible error messages of NSError thrown in this method.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> one must know all the possible error
>   values that are returned because a
>   user won't be pleased to see something
>   like "Error %^@)$()(!)#()+! code
>   123_123443 blah"i.e.something
>   incomprehensible to him

I don't know all the possible errors that particular method can return but I think it is safe enough to use the `localizedDescription` method of `NSError` to present the error to the user.

From [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html):

> Error objects in the Cocoa domain are
>   always localized and ready to present
>   to users, so they can often be
>   presented without further evaluation.